# create bitmap image from data being sent to a printer

Tags: serial, windows

I have a device that sends its screen capture to serial and parallel printers. I received  raw data from serial port being sent to printer. I want to connect this port to my PC instead of a printer and want to create a bitmap or any format of image file so that I can have a softcopy instead of a hardcopy. The device sends data compatible with EPSON FX-80, FX-100 and laser printer 75dpi, 100dpi and 150dpi format.
[Raw data on printer port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJYkZ.png)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. " I captured the data from serial port being sent to printer." Your post suggests that you have already done it.

Comment: By capture I meant I have received raw hex data from serial port on PC. Question updated.

Comment: It's definitely possible to emulate a printer in software, but it may be a fair amount of work. Do you know what format the printer supports? That's a good place to start.

Comment: *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*

Comment: @Sidk - Hi, Please *quickly* edit your question to add a *clear, well-defined, reasonably-scoped and on-topic* question. Asking if something is possible, as your question says at the moment, is a yes/no answer with no technical value here, which could lead to this question being closed. If you really meant to ask *how* to do this, you need to (quickly!) edit the question and explain where exactly you are stuck, and what on-topic question you have. If you are asking about writing Windows software, that is off-topic *here* so please *clarify your question*. Thanks

Comment: The only part of this that is, arguably, Electrical Engineering, is capture, but not so much because that can (usually) be done with simple off-the-shelf hardware. The big question is what you do with the output. Very different taking simple text printer data with a few formatting codes vs. handling an image bitmap vs. postscript. So really need a **lot** more details - too vague as written. And likely better on a different site anyway as this is a PC software/emulation issue and not (fundamentally) a hardware problem.

Comment: What operating system is on the printing device? What is it? Why do you want an image rather than a printer file?

Comment: By image I mean what if I want to replace printer with a PC which receives data from sending device and gives me a softcopy in form of a picture (image) bitmap or something.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the device in question, it's hard to give
a good answer, but here goes.

I believe that understanding the printer commands from the byte-stream
is too big a job, requiring much study and knowledge.

There exist hardware devices that do exactly this job, producing
files in many formats, including PDF if required.

A quick search has found two such products:

- [Serial Printer Logger](https://www.aggsoft.com/serial-printer-logger.htm)

  > Serial Printer Logger can replace your old dot-matrix printers and collect data in real-time to a binary log file, a PDF, or a Word electronic document.
- [Photologic Print Data Capture Hardware](http://www.photologic.ca/cap.html)

  > Our print capture solutions can help you modernize older equipment by giving you an electronic record rather than a hardcopy printout.

If you have the budget for one of these devices, it will solve the
problem. Otherwise, the task will be really complicated.

Comment: Noted. But I want to eliminate printer without adding any other device. I have added a snap of the data received on serial port with 75dpi printer selected, you may have a look.

Comment: @harrymc are you sure the "Serial Printer Logger" by AGG Software is hardware/a device? It looks like software to me....

Comment: Yes, it does look so, and it has a trial version. Perhaps it's the software you're looking for.

Comment: I just checked it. It logs the data travelling on port. What I want a sort of a converter that pick data being sent on serial port and converts data into bitmap or any file format so that I can have a softcopy.

Comment: This leaves the Photologic device.